# objective-c, possible to queue async NSURLRequests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlrequest

I realize this question sounds contradictory.  I have several Async requests going out in an application.  The situation is that the first async request is an authentication request, and the rest will use an access token returned by the successful authentication request.

The two obvious solutions would be:

1. run them all synchronous, and risk UI block.  (bad choice)
2. run them async, and put request 2-N in the completion handler for the first one.  (not practical)

The trouble is that the subsequent requests may be handled anywhere in the project, at anytime.  The failure case would be if the 2nd request was called immediately after the 1st authentication request was issued, and before the access token was returned.

My question thus is, is there any way to queue up Async requests, or somehow say not to issue them until the first request returns successfully?

EDIT:

Why (2) is not practical:  The first is an authentication request, happening when the app loads.  The 2nd+ may occur right away, in which case it is practical, but it also may occur in a completely separate class or any other part of a large application.  I can't essentially put the entire application in the completion handler.  Other accesses to the API requests may occur in other classes, and at anytime.  Even 1-2 days away after many other things have occurred.

SOLUTION:

```
//pseudo code using semaphore lock on authentication call to block all other calls until it is received

// at start of auth
_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

// at start of api calls
if(_accessToken == nil && ![_apiCall isEqualToString:@"auth]){
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}

// at end of auth with auth token
dispatch_semaphore_signal([[SFApi Instance] semaphore]);
_accessToken = ...;
```

Comment: I did something like this... coded the stuff synchronously first, then moved it to separate threads once I knew it was working. Your case  seems like an application for either a semaphore (a "barrier" is even better) or a serial queue where the first work item is the authentication request. See the grand central dispatch docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2

Comment: In addition to @RobP comment, you could also use NSOperation and take advantage of it's addDependency: method. Here is a link to the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1

Comment: Why exactly is #2 not practical?

Comment: Synchronous requests don't block the UI if they don't run on the main thread.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why your idea 2 isn't practical.

Comment: I added an edit on why (2) may not be practical.

Comment: A semaphore/lock may be a simple approach to this, where the first locks the semaphore and the remaining requests need to wait on it.  It can block the subsequent requests as long as the lock doesn't block the application overall, which seems good.

Comment: I do this same thing in my apps.  I have one request that auths.  Once I have the auth I cache it and use the token there ever after until the token is revoked by my server.  So when I'm doing 2-N I always first check to see is my local token has content in the string.  If not I either just don't do it or I go out and get a token.

Comment: Added solution using semaphores.  @RobP, the credit for the idea is yours if you post a quick answer for it.

Comment: thanks I will post one now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I always find it easiest to write the code synchronously and get it running on the UI thread first, correctly, just for debugging. Then, move the operations to separate threads and make sure you handle concurrency.

In this case the perfect mechanism for concurrency is a *semaphore*; the authentication operation clears the semaphore when it is done, and all the other operations are blocking on it. Once authentication is done, floodgates are open.

The relevant functions are dispatch_semaphore_create() and dispatch_semaphore_wait() from the Grand Central Dispatch documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2

Another excellent solution is to create a queue with a *barrier*:

A dispatch barrier allows you to create a synchronization point within a concurrent dispatch queue. When it encounters a barrier, a concurrent queue delays the execution of the barrier block (or any further blocks) until all blocks submitted before the barrier finish executing. At that point, the barrier block executes by itself. Upon completion, the queue resumes its normal execution behavior.

Looks like you got it running with a semaphore, nicely done!

Comment: Both approaches are suboptimal and impractical: no way to cancel the subsequent tasks, a thread will be occupied and blocked just for waiting for a result. And I fear, your second idea isn't feasible at all: "barriers" in dispatch lib are meant to solve a different problem.

Comment: proof by bald assertion? you haven't really explained why they are impractical, and indeed I've implemented an app along these lines that works quite nicely. Whether or not the subsequent tasks are cancelable depends on the details of the implementation and can be permitted. A thread is not a very heavyweight object. In effect you can either manage your own task list and scheduling and dispatch, or use the OS mechanisms to do it.

Comment: Canceling a semaphore which blocks a thread is actually quite difficult, if not impossibly if you take all race conditions into account and try to solve it. Then, if you enqueued a block in a dispatch queue, this block will eventually execute, no matter what, unless the program terminates prematurely (crashes). A thread is not at all lightweight - especially on mobile devices. Creating a thread just for getting a result from an asynchronous task and block it until that happens is a code smell - and can be avoided easily with suitable patterns for an asynchronous programming style.

Comment: excellent proof by bald assertion with no references, profiling, or measurement. anyway I think you misunderstand what I am proposing, as the purpose of the threads is not to retrieve the results of an async task but to dispatch the other, dependent tasks. Cheers.

Comment: Some good specifics on thread costs are in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW7 under "Thread Costs". They are not especially lightweight, but are certainly a reasonable solution for some cases depending on how many, for how long, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a case where you'd want to use NSOperation's dependencies

From apple docs:

> Operation Dependencies
>
> Dependencies are a convenient way to execute operations in a specific order. You can add and remove dependencies for an operation using the addDependency: and removeDependency: methods. By default, an operation object that has dependencies is not considered ready until all of its dependent operation objects have finished executing. Once the last dependent operation finishes, however, the operation object becomes ready and able to execute.

note that in order for this to work, you must subclass NSOperation "properly" with respect to KVO-compliance

> The NSOperation class is key-value coding (KVC) and key-value observing (KVO) compliant for several of its properties. As needed, you can observe these properties to control other parts of your application.

Comment: You don't have to subclass NSOperation to add dependencies. You could use the apple provided subclasses: NSBlockOperation, NSInvocationOperation, etc..

Comment: You should provide a workable example and show how elaborate and cumbersome the solution will become when using NSOperation dependencies ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have it both ways-- there's no built-in serialization for the NSURLConnection stuff. However, you are probably already funneling all of your API requests through some common class anyway (presumably you're not making raw network calls willy-nilly all over the app).

You'll need to build the infrastructure inside that class that prevents the execution of the later requests until the first request has completed. This suggests some sort of serial dispatch queue that all requests (including the initial auth step) are funneled through. You could do this via dependent NSOperations, as is suggested elsewhere, but it doesn't need to be that explicit. Wrapping the requests in a common set of entry points will allow you to do this any way you want behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Use blocks... 2 ways that I do it:

First, a block inside of a block...

```
    [myCommKit getPlayerInfoWithCallback:^(ReturnCode returnCode, NSDictionary *playerInfo) {
        if (playerInfo) {
            // this won't run until the first one has finished
            [myCommKit adjustSomething: thingToAdjust withCallback:^(ReturnCode returnCode, NSDictionary *successCode) {
                if (successCode) {
                // this won't run until both the first and then the second one finished

                }
            }];
        }
    }];
    // don't be confused.. anything down here will run instantly!!!!
```

Second way is a method inside of a block

```
    [myCommKit getPlayerInfoWithCallback:^(ReturnCode returnCode, NSDictionary *playerInfo) {
        if (playerInfo) {
             [self doNextThingAlsoUsingBlocks];
        }
    }];
```

Either way, any time I do async communication with my server I use blocks.  You have to think differently when writing code that communicates with a server.  You have to force things to go in the order you want and wait for the return success/fail before doing the next thing.  And getting used to blocks is the right way to think about it.  It could be 15 seconds between when you start the block and when it gets to the callback and executes the code inside.  It could never come back if they're not online or there's a server outage.

Bonus way.. I've also sometimes done things using stages:

```
        switch (serverCommunicationStage) {
            case FIRST_STAGE:
            {
                 serverCommunicationStage = FIRST_STAGE_WAITING;
                 // either have a block in here or call a method that has a block
                 [ block {
                     // in call back of this async call
                     serverCommunicationStage = SECOND_STAGE;
                 }];
                 break;
            }
            case FIRST_STAGE_WAITING:
            {
                 // this just waits for the first step to complete
                 break;
            }
            case SECOND_STAGE:
            {
                 // either have a block in here or call a method that has a block
                 break;
            }
        }
```

Then in your draw loop or somewhere keep calling this method.  Or set up a timer to call it every 2 seconds or whatever makes sense for your application.  Just make sure to manage the stages properly.  You don't want to accidentally keep calling the request over and over.  So make sure to set the stage to waiting before you enter the block for the server call.

I know this might seem like an older school method. But it works fine.

Comment: It's not "old school" at all: it's actually a common pattern whose name is "Continuation". A "Continuation" is basically the code that get executed when the result of an asynchronous task is available. Here in this case, it's a "Block", or better the "completion block", which also has a parameter which passes back the result of the task to the call-site. There are a few other implementation forms which implement a "continuation": completion handler, promises, futures, delegates - and they can be asynchronous (non-blocking) and synchronous (blocking) style.

Comment: Thanks.  But no I meant that using stages with a draw loop instead of blocks might be old school.