# Objective C - depended asynchronous requests

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, token

I'm working on an app, where I have lot of async calls to our server.
My problem is that many of these calls uses a token, and for everytime I call the server with a token, I will receive a new token. This means that my async calls get synchronized because they new the newest token.

I'm using Jonathan Willings code from here: https://gist.github.com/jwilling/7209108

This is ok, but it blocks my UI and I cannot figure out why.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the code look like that calls it?  (Also, when your UI blocks, you can pause your app in the debugger and see what the main thread is doing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the unclear question. I'm using the ASIFormDataRequest. I got it working by using a semaphore answered in this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021948/objective-c-possible-to-queue-async-nsurlrequests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021948/objective-c-possible-to-queue-async-nsurlrequests). It's important though to reset the semaphore everytime, so that the signal doesn't increment for every time no calls are waiting.